# Convert PostgreSQL Query into corresponding Hibernate Query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I need corresponding Hibernate Query for the `PostgreSQL query.`

Here is query

```
select DATE(row_created) from DemoTable
```

where `DATE` is inbuilt function in PostgreSQL and `row_created` is column in `DemoTable` having data type of `timestamp without time zone`.

Here is my POJO class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate")
public class Candidates { 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int candidateId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "mail_id")
    private String mailId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "experience")
    private String experience;

    @Column(name = "ctc")
    private String ctc;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String company;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "notice_period")
    private String noticePeriod;

    @Column(name = "prefered_job_location")
    private String preferedJobLocation;

    @Column(name = "resume_filepath_name")
    private String resumeFilepathName;

    @Column(name = "primary_skill")
    private String primarySkill;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Short isActive;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "row_created")
    private Date rowCreated;

    @Column(name = "row_altered")
    private Date rowAltered;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="tracker_fk_id")
    private Tracker trackerFk;

}
```

Can anyone help to get equivalent Hibernate Query for that.

Thanks

Comment: can you share how your entity look like?

Comment: Hello,I have updated my Entity as well.I need only date part in my HQL from database table "candidate" having column row_created with data type timestamp with out time zone.Hope you got my point,if not let me know.

Comment: So do you want the Hibernate query (HQL) or do you want JPA (JPQL)?

Comment: Check my answer update, the 3ed case i think you need something like that @Sunil Kumar :)

Comment: Yeahh.that works for me :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Query like this:

```
//Select your object that you want
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SELECT a FROM DemoTable a WHERE mycondition");
```

**1-In case to get single date**

```
//Get result list or a single result like what you want
DemoTableEntity myresult = (DemoTableEntity) query.getSingleResult();

//get the date from this result
Date mydate = myresult.getRowCreated();
```

**2-In case to get liste of date**

```
List<Date> listeDate = new ArrayList<>();

List<DemoTableEntity> list = query.getResultList();

for(DemoTableEntity ent : list){
   listeDate.add(ent.getRowCreated());
}
```

**3-In case to get list of result of one column**

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SELECT a.rowAltered FROM Candidates a");
List<Date> dates = query.getResultList();
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the data, then you can do as "Youcef Laidani" said, so you can trim the time in the field getter method or trim it when needed.

But if you are looking to use that in a where condition then use BETWEEN statement instead of equal

```
SELECT a FROM DemoTable WHERE a.row_created BETWEEN :from AND :to
```

where to is the target date +1 day

```
example values: 
from = 2016-11-10 00:00:00
to   = 2016-11-11 00:00:00
that means where created_date = 2016-11-10
```

Comment: Hello Ali,for time being Youcef query works fine for me,will try for your logic as well.Thanks for your response :)